# Pandas isnull.().sum() list all all columns without summary

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a database that has 115 column headers and I need to summarize which columns have null values.  When I use `df.isnull().sum()` it just gives me the top 30 and the bottom 30 I need to list all columns how would I go about this?

```py
df.isnull().sum()
```

Comment: It is just displaying the top and bottom 30, but all are calculated.  To order them: `df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)`.

Comment: It gives you all, but only print 30 due to the print limit.

Comment: I was able to create an object obj = df.isnull().sum() then iterate over the object to using a for loop but I want to store the iteration as a data frame column='Column Header', column 2 = 'Sum of Null' How would I go about creating a dataframe from a for loop?

Comment: The output of your command should produce a Series. It should be possible to save that output to a variable, then filter where the column value for sum is greater than zero. Once filtered. `Series.index.values` will produce the index values that correspond to your column names.

Answer (score 6):

```
obj = file.isnull().sum()
for key,value in obj.iteritems():
    print(key,",",value)
```

this line of code worked for me was able to copy to comma-separated CSV

Answer (score 3):

You can also increase the number of rows that will display:

```
pd.options.display.min_rows = 115
df.isnull().sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a beginner pandas user. However, this is a bigenner code that solves your issue, where you store the sum of `NaNs` in another variable. Then, prints it with `.to_string()`

```
var = df.isnull().sum()
print(var.to_string())
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.set_option("display.max_columns" , None)

dataframe.isnull().sum
```

Use these two commands one by one then you will get your answer

cell 1 run this : `pd.set_option("display.max_columns" , None)`

cell 2 run this : `dataframe.isnull().sum`